# Table denormalization

Tags: sql, sql-server, denormalization

I have to denormalize existing table and save all the data that is already there.
Previously my tables structure was

```
TABLE A:
[id] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
[name] NVARCHAR(100)
[countryID] INT

TABLE B:
[id] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
[countryName] NVARCHAR(100)
```

New TableA structure:

```
TABLE A:
[id] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
[name] NVARCHAR(100)
[countryName] NVARCHAR(100)
```

I wonder if there is more elegant solution than this one

```
--BACKUP TABLE TO VARIABLE
DECLARE @backup TABLE (
            [Id] INT NOT NULL,
            [Name] NVARCHAR (1000) NOT NULL,
            [CountryId] INT NULL,
INSERT INTO @backup SELECT * FROM [dbName].[TableA]

--RECREATE THE TABLE WITH NEW STRUCTURE
DROP TABLE [dbName].[TableA]
CREATE TABLE [dbName].[TableA]
        (
            [Id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
            [Name] NVARCHAR (1000) NOT NULL,
            [CountryId] NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
            CONSTRAINT [PK_TableA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
            (
                [Id] ASC
            ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbName].[TableA] ON --Required to save original Id's

--INSERT DATA FROM BACKUP TABLE
INSERT INTO [dbName].[TableA]([Id],[Name],[CountryId])
SELECT 
backup.[Id],
backup.[Name],
[dbName].[TableB].[Name],
FROM @backup backup
LEFT JOIN [dbName].[TableB] on backup.[CountyId] = [dbName].[TableB].[Id]

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbName].[TableA] ON
```

Comment: Only thing I would ask is why is Country Code a `varchar(100)`? The ISO 3166 standard maintains a list of numeric values for countries. I would make sense to put these into a table and sync your new table's CountryID to that numeric value.

Comment: Are you aware that this is recipe for disaster? You're adding redundant data to your database. That might actually slow things down instead of improving performance (which is the usual excuse to denormalize)

Comment: Don't backup the table to a variable.  Use a real table -- not even a temporary table.  That way, the backup data will persist until you decide to remove it.  You may also need to be sensitive to transactions that occur on the tables while you are executing this transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different people may have different choice. But for me, I will chose this steps to do the same-

1. BACKUP Table-A
2. Alter Table-A and add new column "countryName"
3. Update data in countryName column by left joining with Table-B
4. Alter Table-A to DROP column "countryID"
5. DROP Table-B (Based on Requirement)

Note: I would chose Alter Table-A option just to avoid Restore of table in case of data lose.

Comment: This is how I would do it as well, if I actually approve the need for this denormalization.

Comment: In your Script I found you drop your table and created again with new column and then restore data from Backup. There are slight difference in my approach compare to you. Regarding de normalization, Its must be a requirement for you so no argument here. But this is not good at all :)

Answer (score 1):

I would be cautious about your solution.  It is not thread-safe (that is, if other threads are modifying the tables, you could lose data).  You also run the risk of losing the back up table, if something happens to the database -- say if the database goes down after the `drop` but before the `insert`.

You are actually just adding a new column to `TableA`.  Well, you can do that directly:

```
alter tableA add column countryName varchar(100);

update a
    set countryName = b.countryName
    from tableA a join
         tableB b
         on a.CountyId = b.id;
```

Both of these should be "safe" operations in the database.  I would still backup a production database before executing them.  However, they should be fine.

The one caveat is that if `TableA` is really big, altering the table might take some time.  You might want to test that out on a development/staging box before changing the table on production.